# twisting sheaf of toric projective bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, toric-geometry

Let $X_{\Sigma} = \mathbb{P}_{X_{\Sigma'}}(\mathcal{L_1}\oplus\mathcal{L_2}),X_{\Sigma'}$  be toric varieties ('good' if it's necessary), $\mathcal{L}_i\in \mathrm{Pic}(X_{\Sigma'})$ and $\pi:X_{\Sigma}\to X_{\Sigma'}$  be a morphism of projection. 
For example $X_{\Sigma'} = \mathbb{P}^1$ and $X_{\Sigma} = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(d))$

So my question is how to express twisting sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X_{\Sigma}}(1)$ in terms of $\Sigma$ or $\Sigma'$.

More precisely there is a representation of $\mathcal{O}_{X_{\Sigma}}(1) = \sum a_i D_i$ as sum of $T$-stable divisors which are correspond to rays of $\Sigma$ and i want determine $a_i$.

Comment: @TonyBlair'sWitchProject $\mathbb{P}_X(F)$ is a relative Proj
in case $F$ is the sum of invertible bundles  $\mathbb{P}_{X_{\Sigma'}}(F)$ equipped with the structure of toric variety and morphism of projection is toric

Comment: @TonyBlair'sWitchProject i have corrected my question

Comment: @TonyBlair'sWitchProject is it clear now?